# Sybase - Strip off hour, minutes and seconds

Tags: sybase

I have this datetime:

```
09/29/2012 08:23:00.65
```

How can I just have this, using sybase:

```
09/29/2012
```

**UPDATE:**

How can I transform date '16-01-2017' into 20170116?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `convert(date, <your-datetime-field>)`

For example:

```
select convert(date, '09/29/2012 08:23:00.65')
```

Returns:

`09/29/2012`

**Edit per your comment**
*The code above works for me, but you can use the following as well:*

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), '09/29/2012 08:23:00.65', 101)
```

**Edit per your update**
First, I suggest that you have a look [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Convert.htm) at sybase documentation for `convert`

Second it can be achieved like this:

```
select convert(char(10), convert(datetime, '16-01-2017',105), 112)
```

Comment: This is wrong. First of all, it is dd/mm/yyyy and returns mm/dd/yyyy.Second, it returns 09/29/2012 00:00:00